# Multiplying a positive $\ell^2$ sequence with an unbounded positive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was wondering if it is true that for every positive $\ell^2$ sequence $(x_n)_n$ there exists a positive sequence $(y_n)_n$ with $y_n\to\infty$ such that $(y_n x_n)_n$ is still in $\ell^2$? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question for $\ell^1$ because the squaring is irrelevant:

There is a sequence of positive integers $N_1<N_2<N_3<\cdots$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=N_m}^\infty x_n< 2^{-m}$.  Take $y_n=m$ when $N_m\leq n<N_{m+1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response!